# css: checking if sibling is focused

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way I can check if `.link:focused` and then change the display property of `.box`? I am trying to avoid JS if possible for this but not sure if can be done purely CSS or SCSS way.

```
<a class="link" title="foo">My Title</a>
<div class="container">
   <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, you can use the sibling selector `+`. The whole selector should look something like this `a:focus + .container ,box`. I suggest you'll get familiar with CSS selectors, because they can save quite a bit of JS code sometimes.

Comment: @Gil you have a typo: `a:focus + .container > .box`

Comment: I know, but I can't edit it anymore :(

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) (`+`) as Gil suggested. Also, make sure to set an `href` attribute to make your `<a>` anchor element focusable. I suggest a hash (`#`) so that the page does not navigate.

Additinally, you can throw in a [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) (`>`) between the `.container` and `.box` to improve specificity.

```css
.container > .box {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

a:focus + .container > .box {
  width: unset;
  height: unset;
  background: #FF0;
}

a:focus + .container > .box::after {
  content: 'Focused';
}
```

```html
<a class="link" title="foo" href="#">My Title</a>
<div class="container">
   <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It was `:after` in CSS 2.1, in CSS 3 it has been `::after` for the past 11 years. *to improve specificity* Higher specificity in most cases is worse than lower specificity. You should always strive to use the lowest necessary specificity.